# How to match a dash-separated list without matching space?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match a dash separated list in Javascript. Given the following values: `hello-match-world` and `hello-match`, I want to match and capture `match` there.

I have used `/\bmatch\b/` to match it, but after some testing it will also match `hello match world` and `hello match`. How can I only match the world surrounded with hyphen or space?

I have tried positive lookahead like this: `/match(?=\s*)/`, but I cannot handle the space before the word. Which I want `match`(i.e. no surround space) to be a match as well.

Comment: `/(?<=[\s-])match(?=[-\s])/` or `/(?<![^\s-])match(?![^-\s])/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either assert a `-` to the left, or a hyphen to the right and use the word boundary to prevent a partial match.

```
\bmatch(?=-)|(?<=-)match\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sJ4tIV/1)